# Updating the values of a dictionary based on keys of another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

I have a dictionary that contains different values for words, some of them being morphological forms of the same word:

```
test_dictionary = {'und': 2,
 'der': 326,
 'die': 667,
 'in': 46456,
 'den': 16628950,
 'zu': 222,
 'Buch': 300,
 'Büchern': 20,
 'Lehrerin': 20,
 'Lehrerinnen': 2}
```

I want to cluster the words that stem from the same words and assign them the same value, which is the sum of the values of the words in that cluster. So:

```
new_dictionary = {'und': 2,
     'der': 1159,
     'die': 1159,
     'in': 46456,
     'den': 1159,
     'zu': 222,
     'Buch': 320,
     'Büchern': 320,
     'Lehrerin': 22,
     'Lehrerinnen': 22}
```

What I did so far was to use Spacy for stemming:

```
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
test_list = list(test_dictionary.keys())
test_lemmas = [nlp(a)[0].lemma_ for a in test_list]
test_counter = Counter(test_lemmas)
counter_test_dictionary={}
for key, value in test_counter.items():
    counter_test_dictionary[key] = value
counter_test_dictionary

{'und': 1,
 'der': 3,
 'in': 1,
 'zu': 1,
 'Buch': 2,
 'Lehrerin': 2}
```

I know how to sum values of a dictionary, but how do I make use of this `counter_test_dictionary` (if I can) to know exactly what values to sum. Note: this example is a small snippet from a huge dataset of words, so I might also need to check out how computationally expensive this is.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
word2lemma = {word: nlp(word)[0].lemma_ for word in test_dictionary}
new_dictionary = defaultdict(int)
for word, value in test_dictionary.items():
    new_dictionary[word2lemma[word]] += int(value)
new_dictionary = dict(new_dictionary)
```

Comment: Sorry I un-approved your answer, it was my mistake too because I accidentally wrote some values as strings. Your code only keeps the main word, so it doesn't return all the original keys.